# Terraform import Kubernetes secret

Tags: postgresql, terraform

I am trying to import an existing kubernetes secret into my Terraform state.

The secret resource should be located in a module, together with postgres resources. The idea is that I create the postgres user credentials and put them straight in a K8S secret.

The resource looks like this:

```
resource "kubernetes_secret" "database-credentials" {
  metadata {
    name = "${var.name}-database-credentials"
  } 
  data = {
    username = "${var.name}_user"
    password = random_password.password.result
  }
  type = "Opaque"
}
```

Then, I try to import it with the following command:
`terraform import module.<module_name>.kubernetes_secret.database-credentials default/<existing-secret-name>`

Now, the problem is that this command fails with the following error message:

```
Error: Error initializing PostgreSQL client: error detecting capabilities: error PostgreSQL version: pq: no PostgreSQL user name specified in startup packet
```

I have no idea why the PostgreSQL client needs to do anything here or why it fails. There are postgres resources defined above the kubernetes secret resource config but I just want to import a k8s secret. I have defined all necessary environment variables needed. `terraform apply` works fine when I run it without the secret.

Could someone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: Are you saying you get that error when running the import? That looks like the error you might get when running a plan where you create the Postgresql host and attempt to use it at the same time but shouldn't happen during an import.

Comment: Yes I did get that error during an import, but see answer below what I did to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out myself.

https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-postgresql/issues/2#issuecomment-567887609

TLDR: add `expected_version = "<YOUR_POSTGRES_VERSION>"` to the postgres provider block.